# WordPress Active Tabs

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress theme I included the following in the header.php for the menu:

```
    <li><a href="about-us" class="<?php echo $about; ?>">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact" class="<?php echo $contact; ?>">Contact</a></li>
```

However when I include the following code in the about us template:

```
    <?php   /* Template Name: About Us */ ?>
    <?php $about = "active"; ?>
    <?php get_header() ?>
```

The tab doesn't become "active", though if I include the code snippet `$about = "active";` in the header.php file it works. Why is this? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the fact that the get_header() function isn't aware of the $about variable. This has to do with [the PHP variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

The way I solved this is by using the [Wordpress API to generate a menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus). This way, each page will automatically detect if it's the 'active' page and add that class to its relevant menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest you to make your menu dynamic using wp_nav_menu(). However if you do not wish to use wp_nav_menu(), you could also make the menu items active using the page id in header.php